# What's the best way to turn a .Net class into a SQLite table?

Tags: .net, database, class, sqlite

I have a bunch of classes in a WPF application, that read data from a REST service.
I've decided to save time and traffic by saving the replies that rarely change in a SQLite database. I'm planning to use [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) to access the db.

My question is: what's the best (read: elegant, fast, nice) way to take class properties and turn it into a SQL Create statement? Yes, I can start typing and configuring, and it would take less than an hour, but Ihave a nagging feeling I am missing a trick or two here.

Any reply acceptable: Visual Studio tool, Linq, a class attribute I'm missing - I am in a learning mode/mood.

Thanks for your time and replies.
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an ORM like NHibernate, and have it automatically generate your schema for you?  this both handles your issue at hand, and also saves you from a bunch of left hand/right hand coding to populate your tables down the road.

Comment: It's a small project. But let's say, for education sake, that I'll try NHibernate. What's a best place to start? Does it even work with SQLite? Thanks

Comment: Yep, works with SQLite among others (FYI I use NHibernate for all of my projects these days since it's such a timesaver).  I have a series of tutorials on my blog (in my profile) There's also info at nhforge.org

Comment: Thanks guys. Will take a look at all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You should find yourself an ORM which will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Devart dotConnect for SQLite - http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/, this product contains an enhancement of LINQ to SQL which works with SQLite databases. This solution will be very elegant and fast.